# Sparql query returns undesired results when using blank nodes (rdflib)

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, rdflib, blank-nodes

I use `rdflib` python library to model a graph of contacts, and perform `sparql` queries to retrieve who knows who. This works fine when people as added as `URIRef`, but not when using `BNode`.

The example graph can be represented as follow:

```
bob   - knows -> linda
alice - knows -> linda
tom   - knows -> linda
        knows -> bob
```

Only Tom knows Bob, and no one knows Tom.

I perform the following 2 queries:

1. The first one to retrieves Tom; it works as expected.
2. In the second query, I use Tom node id to retrieve who knows him. I expect an empty list. When Tom is added as a `URIRef`, it works as expected. However, when Tom is added as a `BNode`, this query returns 3 names!

```py
use_blank_node = True # switch to see the undesired behavior happens only with blank node

pred_knows = URIRef("http://example.org/knows")
pred_named = URIRef("http://example.org/named")

def create_graph() -> Graph:
    graph = Graph()

    bob = URIRef("http://example.org/people/Bob")
    linda = BNode()  # a GUID is generated
    alice = BNode()
    tom = BNode() if use_blank_node else URIRef("http://example.org/people/Tom")
    print(f"{str(tom)=}")
    remy = BNode()

    graph.add((bob, pred_named, Literal("Bob")))
    graph.add((alice, pred_named, Literal("Alice")))
    graph.add((tom, pred_named, Literal("Tom")))
    graph.add((linda, pred_named, Literal("Linda")))
    graph.add((remy, pred_named, Literal("Remy")))

    graph.add((bob, pred_knows, linda))
    graph.add((alice, pred_knows, linda))
    graph.add((tom, pred_knows, linda))
    graph.add((tom, pred_knows, bob))

    return graph


find_tom_who_knows_bob_query = f"""SELECT DISTINCT ?knowsbob ?nameofwhoknowsbob
WHERE 
{{ ?knowsbob <{pred_knows}> <http://example.org/people/Bob> ;
             <{pred_named}> ?nameofwhoknowsbob . 
 }}"""


def find_who_know_tom(tom_id) -> str:
    tom_query = f"_:{tom_id}" if type(tom_id) is BNode else f"<{tom_id}>"

    return f"""SELECT DISTINCT ?nameOfWhoKnowsTom
    WHERE 
    {{ ?iriOfWhoKnowsTom  <{pred_knows}> {tom_query} ;
                          <{pred_named}> ?nameOfWhoKnowsTom}}"""


def main():
    graph = create_graph()
    print("=" * 60, "\n", graph.serialize(), "\n", "=" * 60)

    result = list(graph.query(find_tom_who_knows_bob_query))
    assert len(result) == 1 and len(result[0]) == 2
    tom_id = result[0][0]
    print(f"{str(tom_id)=}")
    assert (type(tom_id) == BNode and use_blank_node) or (type(tom_id) == URIRef and use_blank_node is False)
    assert str(result[0][1]) == "Tom"

    query = find_who_know_tom(tom_id)
    print(query)
    result = list(graph.query(query))
    print(
        "They know Tom:", ", ".join([str(r[0]) for r in result])
    )  # why is it not empty when use_blank_node = True
    # prints: "They know Tom: Bob, Alice, Tom"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My question: how to correctly use sparql so that the query also works with blank node ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blank nodes are similar to free variables. From [SPARQL 1.1 Query Language](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#BlankNodesInResults):

> An application writer should not expect blank node labels in a query
> to refer to a particular blank node in the data.

Your second query, instead of

```sql
SELECT ?nameOfWhoKnowsTom WHERE {
   ?iriOfWhoKnowsTom ex:knows _:N6fb3b031995c43cfbf3e257ec0c0eac0 ;
                     ex:named ?nameOfWhoKnowsTom .
}
```

should be like this one:

```sql
SELECT ?nameOfWhoKnowsTom WHERE {
   ?iriOfWhoKnowsTom ex:knows / ex:named "Tom" ;
                     ex:named ?nameOfWhoKnowsTom .
}
```

See also the [blank-nodes](/questions/tagged/blank-nodes) tag info.